# How should I authenticate in SPA using VueJS and Vue Router?

Tags: laravel, authentication, vue.js, vue-router

I am building a SPA website with Laravel for back-end and VueJS for front-end. And now I want to authenticate users in my website. So I used Laravel Passport for that. My question is that how should I keep user access token and refresh token in vue to make another requests for authentication required routes? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Keep 'em in cookies or localStorage.

Comment: @ceejayoz is using localStorage true in this situation? I am just asking because it's my first time building this type of website

Comment: Why wouldn't localStorage be OK?

Comment: @ceejayoz I don't know. Ok then I will use localStorage. I just didn't know :). Thank you for your help

Comment: @ceejayoz Can I ask one more question? How I should keep client secret to get access token for user?